# count null when both of the fields are null

Tags: sql, hiveql

How could I count null(when comment and seller are null) of each date?

the order_time is not a date/time field

Data example on the picture attached to explain what I am trying to achieve here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CahK0.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *as text tables in the question*.

Answer (score 0):

> How could I count null(when comment and seller are null) of each date?

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
select date, sum(case when comment is null and seller is null then 1 else 0 end) as both_null
from t
group by date;
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of where clause select rows only having null in comment and seller column. Then it's just simply count with group by. I have casted order_time column into date as well.

```
select cast(order_time as date) order_date, count(*) null_count
from yourtable
where comment is null and seller is null
group by  cast(order_time as date);
```